# How to discover Uri Scheme from an iOS app?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store

How to discover Uri Scheme from an iOS app?

Example app: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fake-gps-location-for-iphone/id1253820623

I would like to know if it is installed on the iPhone.

I made 2 unsuccessful attempts:

1 - **Iconical app**: Did not list my installed app.

2 - **Download the IPA** and search CFBundleURLSchemes for info.plist

Can anyone give a tip?

I think about using some cordova plugin, but I need to know how to discover Uri Scheme ...

Comment: Searching a little more I saw that not all applications contain "CFBundleURLSchemes" definitions, as they are not necessary. Most of the most popular have them.

Comment: Funny I just came across this. Iconical is my app :) I have to manually search the Info.plist to find URL schemes and add to the Iconical database.

Comment: @Darren The problem is the apps without the URL tags ... Not mandatory information ... The ones I needed none of them informed hehe

Comment: It all started because I need to identify fake location on iOS. I didn't find a compatible plugin, I can't see if they are using the GPS Fake app ... Now I'm trying to compare GPS coordinates with operator antennas (sim card) ...

I am open to suggestions!

Comment: That’s right. Not every app has a URL Scheme. If it’s not in the plist, it doesn’t have one.